# Installing xlwt

Tags: python, installation, xlwt

I am having issues installing the xlwt module in python. Using 64-bit windows operating system. Not sure exactly which folder the unzipped folder should be placed in. Currently I have put it in:

C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages

I have tried using easy_install to install the file but haven't had any luck. Appreciate the feedback!

```
import easy install
runfile('C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/xlwt-0.7.5/setup.py', wdir=r'C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/xlwt-0.7.5')
```

Output

```
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

Comment: where did you download? I only seem to be able to download a tar file not  a zip. When i extract using 7zip, it has only one file with a tar extension inside

Answer (score 2):

Ok - using cmd.exe install using these steps.

Launch cmd.exe and change current working directory to location where the xlwt is. For me its: 
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5

```
cd C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5
python setup.py install
```

Then should be up and running. Hope this helps - it wasn't super clear when reading other documentation.

Comment: i did this, but somehow my python code doesn't recognize the installation

Answer (score 2):

you can install by typing the following command in cmd:

```
python -m pip install xlwt
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most of Python packages are installed by running the following command:

```
python setup.py install
```

But I recommend you to do the following:

- install [setuptools](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py)
- install [pip](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win/)
- use pip to install xlwt, using the following command `pip install xlwt`

Pip makes managing packages alot easier, this is even more true when you use Windows.